# Using variables in a docker-compose file for binding volumes

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a Flask application that is being run via docker-compose and within that flask application I am writing to some log files to disk. The location of the log files are set through an environment variable, which I pass to docker using a .env file. In my local development, I would like to map the location within docker to the same location on my host system but I would like to use the same LOG_PATH location defined in my .env file:

`.env:`

```
LOG_PATH=/var/log/my_app
```

`docker-compose:`

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    environment:
      - LOG_PATH=$LOG_PATH
    volumes:
      - $LOG_PATH:$LOG_PATH
```

This does not appear to work and it is causing my application to hang. I've tried `${LOG_PATH}:${LOG_PATH}` but that also does not work. The closest I've come to making this work is having the host path set explicitly:

```
 - /var/log/my_app:$LOG_PATH
```

but I would ideally like to have these controlled by the same variable rather than having to change it more than one place.

Comment: The layout of the container's filesystem should be fixed; you shouldn't have to inject the host location of the log directory as an environment variable.  I'd expect something like `volumes: [$LOG_PATH:/app/log]` with a fixed container path to work.  (Or, better, set your application to log to stdout and review the logs with `docker logs`.)